# Hackenbush Diagrams?

Tags: diagrams

I'd like to put diagrams of Hackenbush positions such as the one pictured [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hackenbush) in a paper I'm writing. Anyone know how?

EDIT: I would also be happy with simpler orientations, such as where the edges are all vertical.

Comment: Could you please add a link that shows how these diagrams look like (and what they have to do with fonts).

Comment: @Caramdir I think that a font package would work, like Skak for chess positions.

Comment: related (trackback, actually): http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/2011/02/15/quicklatex-hackenbush-diagram/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Easy answer**: Don't do it. Use a vector graphics program like Inkscape and export to a format that (pdf)LaTeX knows (e.g. pdf or to TikZ code).

**Hard answer**: You can use one of the general purpose drawing libraries for TeX. The following is an example with TikZ.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{hackennode}=[draw,circle,inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt]
\tikzstyle{hackenline}=[line width=3pt]

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[hackennode] (leftleg-1) at (0,0) {};
    \node[hackennode] (leftleg-2) at (1.5,0.75) {};
    \node[hackennode] (leftleg-3) at (1.13,3.0) {};
    \node[hackennode] (leftleg-4) at (2.65,5.3) {};
    \node[hackennode] (rightleg-1) at (3,0) {};
    \node[hackennode] (rightleg-2) at (4.15,0.72) {};
    \node[hackennode] (rightleg-3) at (3.04,2.65) {};
    \node[hackennode] (rightleg-4) at (3.8,4.9) {};

    \node[hackennode] (dress-1) at (4.55,8.3) {};
    \node[hackennode] (dress-2) at (4.91,4.52) {};
    \node[hackennode] (dress-3) at (1.6,5.66) {};

    \node[hackennode] (neck) at (5.3,10.6) {};

    \node[hackennode] (leftarm-1) at (2.25,9.85) {};
    \node[hackennode] (leftarm-2) at (1.53,10.96) {};
    \node[hackennode] (rightarm-1) at (7.56,9.07) {};
    \node[hackennode] (rightarm-2) at (7.2,7.55) {};

    \node[hackennode] (hair-1) at (5.7,12.1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (hair-2) at (8.75,9.85) {};

    \draw[hackenline,blue]
        (leftleg-1) -- (leftleg-2) -- (leftleg-3) -- (leftleg-4) -- (rightleg-4)
        (dress-2) -- (dress-1) -- (dress-3)
        (neck) -- (leftarm-1) -- (leftarm-2)
        (rightarm-1) -- (rightarm-2);
    \draw[hackenline,red]
        (rightleg-1) -- (rightleg-2) -- (rightleg-3) -- (rightleg-4) -- (dress-2)
        (leftleg-4) -- (dress-3)
        (dress-1) -- (neck) -- (rightarm-1);

    \draw[hackenline,red,looseness=1.6]
        (leftarm-2) to[out=45,in=45] ($(leftarm-2)+(-0.76,0.76)$) to[out=225,in=225] (leftarm-2);
    \draw[hackenline,red]
        (neck) to[out=135,in=170,looseness=1.3] (hair-1)
        (hair-1) .. controls (7.9,14.5) and (6.5,8) .. (hair-2);
    \draw[hackenline,blue]
        (neck) to[out=0,in=-10,looseness=1.3] (hair-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This might seem like a lot of code, but it isn't so bad. The trickiest thing is to find the right coordinates (which I did by [including the original picture and placing a grid on top of it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz/9562#9562)).

Some explanation:

- `\tikzstyle` defines some styling options we are going to use later on. You only need to include this once in your document.

  ```
  \tikzstyle{hackennode}=[draw,circle,inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt]
  ```

  This defines how the vertices (“node” in TikZ-speak) are drawn. Change the `minimum size` to make them larger or smaller.

  ```
  \tikzstyle{hackenline}=[line width=3pt]
  ```

  The same, but for the lines. The `line width` key changes line thickness.
- `\begin{tikzpicture}` starts the actual diagram. You can change that to something like `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]` to make the picture smaller/larger. Beware that line thickness and node size are not scaled.
- The syntax to place nodes is

  ```
  \node (〈nodename〉) at 〈position〉 {〈contents〉};
  ```

  The `〈nodename〉` is used to refer to that node later on. `〈position〉` may be a pair of coordinates (if no unit is given, the default is cm). Finally, we don't want any text in our nodes, so we leave `〈contents〉` blank (note that the braces have to be there even if we don't want anything in the node). Additionally we pass the `hackennode` option, which applies the style we defined earlier.
- The syntax to draw straight lines is

  ```
  \draw 〈postition 1〉 -- 〈position 2〉;
  ```

  It is possible to chain several lines together. In addition to `hackenline`, we also pass a color option. Instead we could have defined

  ```
  \tikzstyle{hackenline}=[line width=3pt]
  \tikzstyle{hackenline1}=[hackenline,blue]
  \tikzstyle{hackenline2}=[hackenline,red]
  ```

  and passed the `hackenline1` and `hackenline2` options (this is probably the better solution as it allows to easily change the color­­­­—but I didn't think of this when I wrote the code and don't want to rewrite it).
- Finally, the hardest part is to get good curved lines. We use a combination of the `to[out=〈leaving angle〉,in=〈arriving angle〉]` syntax and Bézier curves (see the TikZ manual for explanations).

[image: the result]

PS: If anyone has a good idea how to draw that circle in her hand (except fudging the position of a `\draw circle` and then overpainting with a filled node), please tell me.

Comment: The following line results in an almost perfect circle (if it weren't for the slight offset at the `hackennode`): `\draw [hackenline, red, out=-45, in=-135, relative, rotate=25] let \n1={0.75} in          (leftarm-2) to +(\n1,\n1) to +(-\n1,\n1) to +(-\n1,-\n1) to (leftarm-2);`   You can control the circle radius by changing the value for `\n1`, and the rotation of the circle around the origin node by changing the value of `rotate`.

Comment: Okay, and the proper way to do it is: `\draw [hackenline,red] let \n1={0.75cm} in let \n2={35} in  (leftarm-2)  +(\n2:2pt+.3pt) arc [start angle=(-90+\n2+atan((2pt+.3pt)/\n1)), end angle=(270+\n2-atan((2pt+.3pt)/\n1)),radius=\n1];`, where`\n1` is the radius of the ball, `\n2` is the angle at which the ball is held, `2pt` is the radius of the `hackennode`s (which would ideally also be parametrised) and `.3pt` is the line width of the `hackennode`s.

Comment: I think I'd put the nodes in afterwards anyways, but if not here's a circle: `\node[draw,circle] (a) {}; \draw (a.north) arc(10:350:1);`.  Of course, you need to experiment to work out what the right angles are.

Comment: @Caramdir Your response was very helpful, and I've gotten it working with Tikz. I'd like to be able to use these in formulas rather than just diagrams--is this possible? For example, I'd like to be able to add 2 blue edges and write Edge+Edge=Stack of edges

Comment: @pgaf: Yes it is. Just put the `{tikzpicture}` environment into the formula. The `baseline` option is useful to get vertical alignment right, and `scale` is useful to get the size right. But best ask a separate question.

Comment: @pgaf: Btw, if you just want a single edge, the shortest form to type it is `\tikz \draw (0,0) -- (1,0);` (without `tikzpicture` environment).

Answer (score 8):

run with `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[dotstyle=o,arrows=o-o,arrowLW=0.2pt,arrowscale=2.5,linewidth=3pt](11,15)
  \psset{linecolor=blue}
  \psline[showpoints,dotscale=0.75](0,0)(1.5,0.75)(1.13,3.0)(2.65,5.3)(3.8,4.9)
  \psline(4.91,4.52)(4.55,8.3)(1.6,5.66)
  \psline(5.3,10.6)(2.25,9.85)(1.53,10.96)
  \psline(7.56,9.07)(7.2,7.55)
  \pccurve[angleB=-10,ncurv=1](5.3,10.6)(5.7,12.1)
  \psset{linecolor=red}
  \psline[showpoints,dotscale=0.75](3,0)(4.15,0.72)(3.04,2.65)(3.8,4.9)(4.91,4.52)
  \psline(4.55,8.3)(5.3,10.6)(7.56,9.07)
  \psline(2.65,5.3)(1.6,5.66)
  \pnode(1.53,10.96){A}\nccircle{A}{0.5}
  \pccurve[angleA=180,angleB=170,ncurv=1](5.3,10.6)(5.7,12.1)
  \psbezier(5.7,12.1)(7.9,14.5)(6.5,8)(8.75,9.85)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you follow the great answer by Caramdir, although it's a bit complicated.

If not, you could draw the diagram with [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) and export it to TikZ with [inkscape2tikz](http://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/).